# Сделать выборку из таблицы MySQL по датам

Tags: mysql

Есть табличка `timetable`, в ней есть два столбца `date_in` (тип `DATE`) и `date_out` (тип `DATE`).

Мне надо получить только те поля, в которых моя переменная `$point` (`DATE`) будет между `date_in` и `date_out`.

Что-то типа

```
SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE $point BETWEEN date_in AND date_out
```

Как это осуществить?

Comment: а этот запрос не сработал что ли?

Comment: D-side, да, могут быть и пересекающиеся диапазоны.

Comment: Saidolim, к сожалению, не сработал

Comment: Перечитал вопрос. Ну, должно работать прямо так, кроме кавычек, правила употребления которых в MуSQL мне незнакомы. И разумеется, надо передать `$point` параметром. И вроде бы и всё.

Comment: До какого-нибудь конкретного сообщения об ошибке добрались?

Comment: D-side, я в phpMyadmin тестирую запрос, ошибки нет, только пустой результат "MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). ( Запрос занял 0.0004 сек. )"

Comment: Гляну, какой запрос мне сгенерит ORM из Rails, отпишусь.

Comment: Спасибо, я сам не пойму, делаю аналогичный запрос с цифрами и все нормально

Comment: Его стоит добавить в вопрос. Оба. С пустым и непустым результатом.

Comment: если очень хочется обрамить идентификатор(ы) кавычками, то следует использовать обратные: `, а не прямые: '

Comment: да я убрал их, но ничего не поменялось( похоже, он $point как string читал и не мог сравнивать. Спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, с костылем заработало. Перевел в `timestamp $points = strtotime($points)`, а в запросе к БД снова его конвертировал.

```
SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME($points) BETWEEN date_in AND date_out
```